# Bash index of first character not given

Tags: bash, shell, expr

So basically something like `expr index '0123 some string' '012345789'` but reversed.
I want to find the index of the first character that is not one of the given characters...
I'd rather not use RegEx, if it is possible...

Comment: Why would you rather not use regex?

Comment: @andlrc I find it difficult to read...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove chars with `tr` and pick the first from what is left

```
left=$(tr -d "012345789" <<< "0123_some string"); echo ${left:0:1}
_
```

once you have the char to find the index follow the same

```
expr index "0123_some string" ${left:0:1}
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gnu awk` and `FPAT` you can do this:

```
str="0123 some string"

awk -v FPAT='[012345789]+' '{print length($1)}' <<< "$str"
4

awk -v FPAT='[02345789]+' '{print length($1)}' <<< "$str"
1

awk -v FPAT='[01345789]+' '{print length($1)}' <<< "$str"
2

awk -v FPAT='[0123 ]+' '{print length($1)}' <<< "$str"
5
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is in Perl but I got to say that I like it:

```
$ perl -pe '$i++while s/^\d//;$_=$i' <<< '0123 some string'
4
```

In case of 1-based index you can use [`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24.) which is initialized at 1 when dealing with single lines:

```
$ perl -pe '$.++while s/^\d//;$_=$.' <<< '0123 some string'
5
```

I'm using `\d` because I assume that you by mistake left out the number 6 from the list `012345789`

Index is currently pointing to the space:

```
0123 some string
    ^ this space
```

Comment: I think index is `1` based.

Comment: @karakfa True might be :-)

Answer (score 0):

Even if shell globing might look similar, it is not a regex.

It could be done in two steps: cut the string, count characters (length).

```
#!/bin/dash
a="$1"                  ### string to process
b='0-9'                 ### range of characters not desired.
c=${a%%[!$b]*}          ### cut the string at the first (not) "$b".
echo "${#c}"            ### Print the value of the position index (from 0).
```

It is written to work on many shells (including bash, of course).

Use as:

```
$ script.sh "0123_some string"
4
$ script.sh "012s3_some string"
3
```